# Codeigniter- Check user exists in month

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, exists

How do we check user exits in this month (The month getting from the submit form) in codeigniter

eg: there is form called salary calculation. Whenever we enter the employees salary need to check exits on that particular month, When submit the form there is field for date to choose which date need to give the salary. from the form we well get user id and month. what is the code model query for it

Table name salary, database date field type is date

Please check my model query code

```
public function ($userid, $month)
{
    $this->db->where('salary_employee_id',$userid);
    $this->db->where('salary_date',$month);
    $query=$this->db->get('salary');
    $query->row_array();

    if(empty($query))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since column `salary_date` in your DB is of type month, so the data in this column will be stored like below:

```
2019-01-12
2019-02-01
2019-03-13
```

I am assuming day could be any day of the month and not necessarily 1st of each month.
So you Mysql Query should use `LIKE` for `salary_date` and should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM `salary` WHERE `salary_employee_id` = '3' AND `salary_date` LIKE '2019-03%'
```

If we assume that User is entering month number in your form. You can change your function like below

```
    public function checkUser($userid, $month)
    {
        //$month contains the month number. If it contains Jan, Feb etc change accordingly.
        $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
        $m = $dateObj->format('m'); // gives month number with 0 as prefix.
        $dateFormat = date('Y') . '-' . $m; //Date Format as used by mysql

        $this->db->where('salary_employee_id',$userid);
        $this->db->like('salary_date', $dateFormat, 'after'); //Construct Like Condition.
        $query=$this->db->get('salary');

        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) { //If Result Found, return true.
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please see that this will only check for current year. If you want to check for previous years or any particular year, you will need to pass the year argument 
as another parameter to this function.

**Update**

Thanks to the comment by @Strawberry, it would be faster to use date range instead of LIKE in the query. So updating the method as below

```
    public function checkUser($userid, $month)
    {

        //$inputDate = date('Y-') . $month;  //Current Year and given month.
        $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', $month);  //Create Date Object. $month is of format Y-m 
        $startDate = $dateObj->format('Y-m-01'); // First Date of Month
        $endDate = $dateObj->format('Y-m-t'); // Last Date of Month

        $this->db->where('salary_employee_id',$userid);
        $this->db->where('salary_date >=', $startDate);
        $this->db->where('salary_date <=', $endDate);       
        $query=$this->db->get('salary');

        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that a range would have the potential to be faster than LIKE, e.g. `salary_date >= 2019-03-01 AND salary_date < 2019-04-01`

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your advice. You are correct and range would be faster. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Whenever using the above codes I am getting an errors like" Message: Call to a member function format() on boolean"

Comment: @VishnuJayaraj Please specify the value of variable $month.

Comment: @VishnuJayaraj I am expecting $month to be numeric value between 1 to 12. If its some other value then you need to construct the date object accordingly.

Comment: @ascsoftw 
this is the my code for month

// controller
$month = date('Y-m', strtotime($_POST['empDateOfSalary']));

//view 
<input type="month"  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo set_value('empDateOfSalary'); ?>"  name="empDateOfSalary">

Comment: @VishnuJayaraj Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: @VishnuJayaraj Please provide the var_dump of $month